# Avoid changing state of class from computed fields - Odoo v8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I have these classes:

```
class bsi_production_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order'

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.production.order.lines', 'production_order', states={'finished': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, string="Order lines", copy=True)
print_orders = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order', 'production_orders', string="Print Orders")
state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('start','Started'),
        ('inprogress','In progress'),
        ('print_order_inprogress','Print Order In Progress'),
        ('finished','Finished'),
        ('cancel','Cancel'),
    ], string='State', index=True,  
    track_visibility='onchange', copy=False,
    help=" ")

class bsi_print_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.print.order'

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order.lines', 'print_order', string="Order lines")
    state = fields.Selection([
        ('inprogress','Draft'),
        ('awaitingraw','Awaiting raw materials'),
        ('work_in_progress','Work in Progress'),
        ('delivered','Delivered'),
        ('cancel','Cancel'),
    ], string="State")
    notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")

class bsi_production_order_lines(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order.lines'

    production_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', string="Production Orders")
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Float(string="Quantity")
    consumed_qty = fields.Float(string="Consumed quantity")
    remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity", compute="_remaining_func") #

    @api.onchange('qty', 'consumed_qty')
    def _remaining_func(self):
        if self.qty or self.consumed_qty:
            self.remaining_qty = self.qty +(-self.consumed_qty)

class bsi_print_order_lines(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.print.order.lines'

    print_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.print.order', string="Print Order")
    production_orders = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', ondelete='cascade', string="Production Order")
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity")
    consumed_qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity consumed")
    remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity", compute="_remaining_func")
    is_book_block = fields.Boolean(string="Is Book Block Done")
    is_binding = fields.Boolean(string="Is Binding Done")
    is_edging = fields.Boolean(string="Is Edging Done")
    isbns = fields.Many2one('worksheets.isbns', string="Worksheet ISBNS")

@api.onchange('qty', 'consumed_qty')
def _remaining_func(self):
    if self.consumed_qty or self.qty:
        self.remaining_qty = self.qty +(-self.consumed_qty)
```

I create a `bsi.print.order` from a `bsi.production.order` class with this method:

```
@api.multi
def create_printy(self):
    copy_record = self.env['bsi.print.order'] 
    for record in self:
        order_lines = []
        for rec in record.order_lines:
            order_lines.append(
            (0,0,
            {
                'isbn': rec.isbn.id,
                'qty': rec.qty,
                }
            ))
        copy_record.create({
            'state' : 'inprogress', 
            'order_lines': order_lines, # here we pass the list of commands that we created earlier
        })
        record.update({'state': 'print_order_inprogress',},)
```

But no matter what state I choose, on `record.update` the state it's always changed on `bsi.print.order`.

I know it's because of the calculated fields, so, is there a way to pass them indirectly? Or a way to not affect the `states` of the child class? (`bsi.print.order`).

**EDIT**

These are the computed fields:

```
class bsi_production_order_lines(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order.lines'

    production_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', string="Production Orders")
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Float(string="Quantity")
    consumed_qty = fields.Float(string="Consumed quantity")
    remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity", compute="_remaining_func") #

@api.onchange('qty', 'consumed_qty')
def _remaining_func(self):
    for s in self:
        for qty in s.isbn:
            if s.qty or s.consumed_qty:
                s.remaining_qty = s.qty +(-s.consumed_qty)
```

On the other class these are the same fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `update` with `write` in your ORM `create` method. I think it is the only problem, because I see computed fields nowhere, so why would the value field change after you modify it from the `create` method? I think that using that `update` in an ORM method is not working, so the state never changes its value.

```
@api.multi
def create_printy(self):
    copy_record = self.env['bsi.print.order'] 
    for record in self:
        order_lines = []
        for rec in record.order_lines:
            order_lines.append(
            (0,0,
            {
                'isbn': rec.isbn.id,
                'qty': rec.qty,
                }
            ))
        copy_record.create({
            'state' : 'inprogress', 
            'order_lines': order_lines, # here we pass the list of commands that we created earlier
        })
        record.write({'state': 'print_order_inprogress',},)
```

Comment: Yes there are two computed fields, but let me try like that :)

Comment: And the update is for the original class, not the target one, but anyways let me see, I don't think that is the problem though.

Comment: The problem is the target class, if I specify on the method 'state':'draft' it should create the target object like that, but it never does, and it's apparently because of two computed fields.

Comment: With write it's the same story, Idk if You an idea about it

Comment: Can you write the *fishy* compute fields? By the way, remove `track_visibility='onchange'` from `state` field in `bsi.production.order`. There is not point in using that parameter if the class does not inherit from `mail.thread` model.

Comment: Okay, removed :), Thank You very much, edited my question